# Nested loop to fill a vector of vector of int in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization

I want to generate an `std::vector` of `std::vector` of `int` in order to represent `k` vectors each of which contains `q` integers in the following manner:

Vector 0: {0,1}

Vector 1: {2,3}

Vector 2: {4,5}

and so no. For this case `k=3` and `q=2`, but they can be any integers >= 1. Due to the fact that this code belongs to a bigger project I have used a lot of declarations among which the following:

```
typedef int BlockId;
typedef vector< BlockId > ParallelClassIds;
```

Let's say that each collection represent the notion of a *"parallel class"* and each integer the IDs of its elements what I call *"blocks"*. I have implemented the following function that tries to create the above structure (`k`, `q` are private variables visible within the C++ class I declared)

```
vector< ParallelClassIds > generateResolutionIds(){

    //The variable to be returned
    vector< ParallelClassIds > ret(k, vector< BlockId >(q));

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){    
        for(int j = 0; j < q; j++){
            printf("Current parallel class size %ld\n", ret.at(i).size());
            ret.at(i).push_back(i*q+j);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

But there are a lot of problems with this functions. First, the `printf()` sometimes print 2, sometimes 3 where I was expecting it to always print `q==2`. Also, instead of the above structure (I checked this by printing the returned structure) it seems to create something like this:

Vector 0: {0,0,0,1}

Vector 1: {0,0,2,3}

Vector 2: {0,0,4,5}

I really have no idea why this behavior is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
vector< ParallelClassIds > ret(k, vector< BlockId >(q));
```

Combined with this line:

```
ret.at(i).push_back(i*q+j);
```

You are creating k vectors of length q, which you then keep appending to the end, bringing them to a length of 2*q.

What you want to do is:

```
vector< ParallelClassIds > ret(k);
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){ 
  ret[i].reserve(q);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the expected result only by replacing this line:

```
ret.at(i).push_back(i*q+j);
```

with this:

```
ret[i][j] = i*q+j;
```